# Transição de cores gradient automaticamente de forma suave

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, possuo uma `div` com o seguinte `css`:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #3e42e4, #e53472);
```

E gostaria que, as cores se alterassem através de JavaScript.

Semelhante ao topo desse site: [Pixelapse](https://www.pixelapse.com/explore)

Como posso fazer isso?

Obs: eu já pensei em algo como:

```
setInterval(function() {
var cor1 = (cor gerada);
var cor2 = (cor gerada);

$("div").css("background", "linear-gradient(to right, cor1, cor2)";
}, 500);
```

Porém não sei como eu geraria as cores e nem se minha lógica está correta.

**Edit**

Obs².: O problema é que assim (como nas respostas sugeridas) as cores vão mudando de uma forma brusca, e no [site de referência](https://www.pixelapse.com/explore), como vocês pode ver as cores vão mudando de acordo com a cor atual, e deixa de uma forma mais "suave". Então é esse efeito que gostaria.

Comment: Acredito que isso lhe ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript

Comment: Obrigado por responder, por favor, leia meu comentário na resposta que foi dada pelo Fernando.

Comment: Sugiro [edit] a pergunta colocando esse detalhe relevante, não está claro só de ver o site em questão (as cores mudam muito devagar) e os comentários nas respostas devem se referir à resposta em si - não acrescentar informações necessárias à pergunta.

Comment: Aos interessados, postei uma versão WebGL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Embora você diga "aleatória", o site em questão parece seguir uma sequência predefinida - e nada aleatória. Se você possui duas cores A e B e gostaria de fazer a transição suave na direção das cores C e D, basta ir incrementando/decrementando cada um dos seus componentes. Se você fizer isso aleatoriamente, dificilmente o resultado será como quer, pois a tendência será sempre de voltar à cor original.

Aqui está um exemplo de uma única transição. Se você quiser mais de uma, uma opção é que ao final da primeira (i.e. quando `progresso` chegar a `1`) você atualiza as cores atuais e sorteia novas cores "alvo", resetando `progresso` para `0` e começando tudo de novo...

```js
var origem1 = [0, 255, 0]; // Cor 1 inicial
var origem2 = [255, 128, 64]; // Cor 2 inicial

var alvo1 = [255, 0, 0]; // Cor 1 final
var alvo2 = [0, 0, 255]; // Cor 2 final

// etc
var predefinidas = [
     [[255,255,0],   [255,0,255]],
     [[255,255,255], [255,255,0]],
     [[0,255,255],   [0,255,0]]
];
var indice = -1;

var progresso = 0; // Progresso em relação a cor 2; começa com 0 (só cor inicial)

// Faz uma média ponderada de cada componente das cores 1 e 2
function calcular(cor1, cor2, progresso) {
  var ret = [];
  for ( var i = 0 ; i < cor1.length ; i++ )
    ret[i] = Math.round(cor2[i] * progresso + cor1[i] * (1 - progresso));
  return ret;
}

setInterval(function() {
  // Atualiza o progresso
  progresso += 0.01;
  if ( progresso > 1 ) { // Se chegou ao final
    progresso = 0; // Reseta o progresso

    origem1 = alvo1; // A cor alvo agora é cor origem
    origem2 = alvo2;

    indice++; // Pega o próximo par de cores
    if ( indice < predefinidas.length ) {
        alvo1 = predefinidas[indice][0];
        alvo2 = predefinidas[indice][1];
    }
    else { // Ou sorteia uma nova cor
        alvo1 = [Math.floor(Math.random()*256), Math.floor(Math.random()*256), Math.floor(Math.random()*256)];
        alvo2 = [Math.floor(Math.random()*256), Math.floor(Math.random()*256), Math.floor(Math.random()*256)];
        // Nota: nada garante que as cores sorteadas não sejam iguais ou muito próximas
    }
  }

  // Calcula as cores para essa "rodada"
  var cor1 = "rgb(" + calcular(origem1, alvo1, progresso).join(",") + ")";
  var cor2 = "rgb(" + calcular(origem2, alvo2, progresso).join(",") + ")";

  // Atribui no CSS
  $("div").css("background", "linear-gradient(to right, " + cor1 + ", " + cor2 + ")");
}, 500);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Exatamente como eu precisava. Somente mais uma dúvida, como faço para adicionar mais cores? Por exemplo origem3, origem4 e alvo3, alvo4?

Comment: @Igor Eu vou atualizar minha resposta com um exemplo. Mas minha recomendação é adaptar [a sugestão do Sergio](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55933/215), pois deve ficar bem mais "leve" pro navegador.

Comment: Tudo bem, @mgibsonbr. Mas, como eu poderia adaptá-la para que ficasse igual ao efeito que vc desenvolveu sendo que os códigos são gerados randomicamente?

Comment: @Igor No código dele a transição ocorre muito rapidamente (menos de 1 segundo), se você quer que mude bem devagar aumente o intervalo em `transition: opacity .8s;` (tente `10s` por exemplo). Se fizer isso, ajuste o `setTimeout` e o `setInterval` de acordo (`10100` ms e `11000` ms por exemplo). Por fim, você pode substituir o `getRandomColor` por outro que busca de uma lista pré-definida, caso não queira sortear um novo par de cores a cada troca (meu exemplo acima faz ambos - primeiro usa cores predefinidas, depois passa pra cores sorteadas quando a lista acaba).

Answer (score 6):

Infelismente CSS transitions não ajudam a fazer transições de gradientes... Para fazer transições suaves de gradientes podes calcular via JavaScript e aplicar a cada mudança (meio pesado, nou vou dar exemplo) ou usas um outro elemento e fazes a transição entre eles com `opacity`.

Para [gerar cores aleatoriamente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1484514/2256325) podes usar assim:

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

Para usar um elemento para ajudar à transição precisas de usar uma combinação de classes CSS e uma função que atribui o novo CSS à div de ajuda/apoio e espera que a transição seja completa e depois esconde-a novamente.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wzkgz28a/

```js
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function colorir() {
    var original = document.getElementById('original'),
        ajuda = document.getElementById('ajuda'),
        a = getRandomColor(),
        b = getRandomColor();

    ajuda.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(to right, ' + a + ', ' + b + ')';
    ajuda.style.opacity = 1;

    setTimeout(function () {
        original.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(to right, ' + a + ', ' + b + ')';
        var subst = ajuda.cloneNode(true);
        subst.classList.add('reset');
        ajuda.parentNode.replaceChild(subst, ajuda);
        ajuda = subst;
        ajuda.style.opacity = 0;
        ajuda.classList.remove('reset');

    }, 5200);
}
setInterval(colorir, 5300);
colorir();
```

```css
div div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #3e42e4, #e53472);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: opacity .8s;
}
#ajuda {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
.reset {
    transition: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="original"></div>
    <div id="ajuda"></div>
</div>
```

Nota que tive de aplicar uma gambiarra para fazer o reset da transição por causa do fluxo do Browser que não aplica diretamente algumas mudanças para melhorar a performance. [Pode lêr-se sobre isso aqui <sup>em Inglês</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16575811/2256325).

Comment: Obrigado, @Sergio. Como sempre à disposição de ajudar. Seu código foi o que chegou mais perto do que eu preciso. O efeito da transição ficou muito bom, mas, dessa maneira, mesma com transição a cor muda, por exemplo, do gradiente entre verde e azul para roxo e laranja e eu preciso que ele mude de cor em relação a atual, por exemplo, ir do azul e ir clareando até chegar em outra cor, etc. Exatamente como no link em que passei na pergunta. Obrigado!

Comment: Confesso que estou com um pouco de dificuldade de entender como essa solução funciona (e adaptá-la pra transição ficar mais lenta - [o melhor que consegui](https://jsfiddle.net/mcbfuj44/1/)). Já vi que quando se faz `ajuda.style.opacity = 1;` o CSS garante que a transição da opacidade ocorra lentamente, mas e quando se faz `ajuda.classList.add('reset');ajuda.style.opacity = 0;ajuda.classList.remove('reset');` o que acontece? No meu entendimento o `opacity` deveria ir pra zero imediatamente, isso está correto? Vi que se não usar no CSS menos da metade do valor do `setInterval` dá problema.

Comment: Por outro lado, se eu tirar o `ajuda.classList.remove('reset');` e movê-lo para logo antes de fazer `ajuda.style.opacity = 1;` [ele parece se comportar mais da maneira que eu esperava...](https://jsfiddle.net/mcbfuj44/2/)

Comment: @mgibsonbr observação pertinente! A minha lógica aparentemente é correta mas [o fluxo do browser está a baralhar as coisas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16575811/2256325). Aparantemente existem gambiarras para isso, junto uma versão e usa meio força bruta e substitui o elemento do DOM: https://jsfiddle.net/wzkgz28a/

Answer (score 6):

Poxa vida... esqueceram do WebGL!

Lado negativo:

- [navegadores antigos não suportam](http://caniuse.com/webgl)
- o código é um pouco maior (pois necessita da inicialização do WebGL)
- requer algum conhecimento de WebGL (pra não errar a ordem das coisas)

Lado positivo:

- muito rápido
- flexibilidade
- pra mim isso é lindo (hehe, desconsidere =)

Ai vai a alternativa usando `canvas` e WebGL:

```js
window.onload = main;

var randomizeColors;
var fixedColors;
var rotacionar0;
var rotacionar1;

function main() {
  // Obtendo o contexto WebGL
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");

  // inicializando o programa GLSL
  var vertexShader = createShaderFromScriptElement(gl, "shader-vs");
  var fragmentShader = createShaderFromScriptElement(gl, "shader-fs");
  var program = createProgram(gl, [vertexShader, fragmentShader]);
  gl.useProgram(program);

  // Criando o buffer e definindo as variáveis de posição dos vértices, além dos dados do buffer
  var aVertexPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aVertexPosition");
  var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array([+1.0, +1.0, +1.0, -1.0, -1.0, +1.0, -1.0, -1.0]),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aVertexPosition);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(aVertexPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  // Criando o buffer e definindo as variáveis de cores iniciais e finais
  var colorLocation0 = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aVertexColor0");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorLocation0);
  var bufferColors0 = gl.createBuffer();

  var colorLocation1 = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aVertexColor1");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorLocation1);
  var bufferColors1 = gl.createBuffer();

  function corAleatoria() {
    var c = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, c);
    var c2 = c.map(function(i) {
      return i / max;
    });
    return c2;
  }

  function corAleatoriaX4() {
    var c = [];
    c.push.apply(c, corAleatoria());
    c.push.apply(c, corAleatoria());
    c.push.apply(c, corAleatoria());
    c.push.apply(c, corAleatoria());
    return c;
  }

  var corInicial, corFinal;

  function setColors(cores0, cores1) {
    corInicial = cores0;
    corFinal = cores1;

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferColors0);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(corInicial), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLocation0, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferColors1);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(corFinal), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLocation1, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  }

  function rotacionar(lista) {
    lista.push(lista.shift());
    lista.push(lista.shift());
    lista.push(lista.shift());
    setColors(corInicial, corFinal);
  }

  rotacionar0 = function() {
    rotacionar(corInicial);
  };
  rotacionar1 = function() {
    rotacionar(corFinal);
  };

  randomizeColors = function() {
    setColors(
      corAleatoriaX4(),
      corAleatoriaX4());
  }

  fixedColors = function() {
    setColors(
      [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]);
  }

  fixedColors();

  var uTempo = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uTempo");
  var tempo = 0.0;

  setInterval(function() {
    gl.uniform1f(uTempo, tempo);

    // desenhando o fundo
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    tempo += 0.1;
  }, 100);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://greggman.github.io/webgl-fundamentals/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<div style="height:0;">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="150"></canvas>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; width:600px; height: 150px; padding: 10px;">
  <button onclick="randomizeColors()">randomizeColors</button>
  <button onclick="fixedColors()">fixedColors</button>
  <button onclick="rotacionar0()">rotacionar0</button>
  <button onclick="rotacionar1()">rotacionar1</button>
</div>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        const float speed = 0.1;

        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
        attribute vec3 aVertexColor0;
        attribute vec3 aVertexColor1;
        uniform float uTempo;

        varying lowp vec4 vColor;

        const float PI = 3.14159265359;
        void main(void) {
            gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
            float t = (cos(uTempo*2.*PI*speed)+1.)*0.5;
            vColor = vec4(aVertexColor0, 1.0) * t + vec4(aVertexColor1, 1.0) * (1.-t);
        }
</script>

<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        varying lowp vec4 vColor;

        void main(void) {
            gl_FragColor = vColor;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Sua alternativa, apesar de parecer ter um grau de complexidade um nível acima das demais alternativas, é bem interessante e acredito que tenha uma ótima performance, e é uma boa alternativa (+1). Mas tem algumas outras desvantagens em relação ao cenário da pergunta, pois você não pode simplesmente, colocar seu `html` de menu, por exemplo, dentro da tag `canvas`, sendo assim você tem que fazer o seu menu flutuar sobre o `canvas` ou algo do gênero. É isso né? Ou não?

Comment: @Fernando está certo, teria que fazer eles se sobreporem. Alterei o exemplo para mostrar uma técnica para se fazer isso.

Comment: Uou, isso é usar um canhão pra matar uma mosca... :P Será que não dá pra fazer algo semelhante com canvas? (i.e. contexto 2D) De todo modo, por mais "pesadona" que seja, essa solução de fato é bem flexível, e dá pra criar uns efeitos bastante interessantes. +1

Comment: Huahuahu... é um canhãozão mesmo... o legal disso, é que depois de vencida a barreira de implementar esse monstrinho (gastei umas 3 horas nisso), efeitos adicionais são mais fáceis de serem adicionados direto nos shaders... por exemplo, alterar a velocidade de transição, no meu exemplo usei `cos` pra fazer transições graduais, mas poderia ser qualquer função. (P.S. to em dúvida no português "canhãozão" tem dois ~ mesmo? que esquisito)

Comment: Sobre usar Contexto 2d... na verdade tenho 0 experiência com isso. Já o WebGL eu já tenho um pouco. Mas tive de relembrar alguns conceitos... por isso fui direto no WebGL.

Comment: Dos 6 meses pra cá desde que vi essa resposta eu acabei fazendo um curso de WebGL, e retiro o que disse sobre a solução ser "pesadona" - vai ver até ela é mais leve do que as alternativas com JS puro rsrs (pelo fato da interpolação das cores ocorrer na GPU). Só que apesar de serem só 4 vértices, eu usaria `uniform`s para setar a 4 cores, em vez de re-popular um `ARRAY_BUFFER` a cada renderização (posso estar enganado, contudo, ainda não tive tempo de adquirir experiência prática com WebGL).

Comment: @mgibsonbr Pode ser pesada pra poder inicializar o contexto do WebGL. `uniform` é para dados globais. Como a cor de cada vértice é distinta, é necessário usar `attribute`. Na verdade são 8 cores, 2 cores para cada um dos 4 vértices. Os arrays de cores não são repopulados a cada frame, somente quando um dos botões de mudança de cor é clicado.

Comment: Offtopic: samples de shaders WebGL (bem maneiro) - https://www.shadertoy.com/browse

Comment: Verdade, eu é que não tinha lido o código com atenção (a função que usa `setTimeout` de fato não atualiza os buffers... e o `attribute` é necessário pra interpolação, sim). Uma última dica: talvez o `setTimeout` pudesse ser substituído por um `requestAnimationFrame`, de modo que o loop parasse quando a página não estivesse visível (poupando recursos, em especial a bateria de dispositivos móveis). P.S. Ops, isso vale pra minha própria resposta também hehe!

Answer (score 5):

Utilize esse codigo para criar as cores aleatórias:

```
function corAleatoria(){
    var pad = '000000';
    return '#' + (pad + Math.floor(0x1000000 * Math.random()).toString(16)).slice(-pad.length);
};
```

E concatene as cores aleatórias com o estilo no momento de seta-lo com jQuery

**Exemplo:**

```js
function corAleatoria(){
    var pad = '000000';
    return '#' + (pad + Math.floor(0x1000000 * Math.random()).toString(16)).slice(-pad.length);
};

setInterval(function() {
  var cor1 = corAleatoria();
  var cor2 = corAleatoria();

  $("body").css({
    background: "linear-gradient(to right, " + cor1 + "," + cor2 + ")"
  });
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> [Confira minha outra solução, com transições suaves, conforme solicitações do AP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55968/2998)

Comment: Obrigado por responder, e é quase isso que eu quero (cheguei nesse mesmo resultado). O problema é que assim as cores vão mudando de uma forma brusca, e no site, como vc pode ver as cores vão mudando de acordo com a cor atual, e deixa de uma forma mais "suave"... Deu pra entender? E obrigado novamente!

Comment: Ótima resposta! Isso não importa nesse caso (em outros pode importar), mas usar `round` num número aleatório faz com que o primeiro `0` e o último `ffffff` tenham a metade da chance de aparecer que todas as outras cores. Um `floor` com `0x1000000` não teria esse problema.

Comment: Vixi @mgibsonbr, você e bfavaretto, estão falando grego para mim, esse código gerar cores aleatórias eu só sei que funciona, mas agora como? Podem editar a resposta com suas observações? Pois não compreendi direito suas observações a ponto de eu mesmo reparar o código. Obrigado!

Comment: Desculpe, eu escrevi aquilo do celular. É o seguinte, suponha que a sua conta dê o valor 500 (decimal). Esse valor com `.toString(16)` resulta em `1f4`. Mas para usar no background você precisaria que fosse `0001f4`, ou seja, precisa acrescentar 3 zeros à esquerda. A quantidade de zeros vai variar de 0 a 5 dependendo do resultado da sua conta.

Comment: O que eu quis dizer é que se você está sorteando um valor de 0 a 9 (pra simplificar) e você usa `round`, os valores `0...0,499` vão virar `0`, os valores `0,5...1,499` vão virar `1`, os valores `1,5...2,499` vão virar `2`, etc, e os valores `8,5...8,999` vão virar `9`. Tanto o 0 quanto o 9 tem metade da chance de aparecer que os outros. Já com `floor`, `0...0,999` vira `0`, `1...1,999` vira `1`, e `9...9,999` vira `9` - todos são sorteados com igual probabilidade. Minha sugestão portanto é `Math.floor(0x1000000*Math.random())`

Comment: @mgibsonbr, editei conforme suas recomendações. Confira se entendi corretamente?

Comment: @Fernando Sim, é isso mesmo. Aliás, interessante esse método de fazer *padding*, não conhecia! Teria me poupado muita raiva nuns projetos passados... :P

Answer (score 5):

Podes fazer da seguinte maneira:

Criar uma função para gerar a cor em RGB de forma aleatória:

```
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

Então dentro do seu setInterval chama a função para gerar a cor random na troca de css:

```
setInterval(function() {
  $("div").css("background", "linear-gradient(to right,"+ getRandomColor()+", "+getRandomColor()+")");
}, 500);
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvmL01xe/).

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Por favor, veja o comentário que fiz sobre a resposta do Fernando.

Answer (score 2):

> Estou postando como outra resposta, pois é totalmente diferente da [primeira resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55930/2998) (que desejo mante-la, pois traz uma abordagem diferente, mas útil). E está foi criada para tratar das novas solicitações feito pelo AP, nos comentários e na edição a pergunta. (transições suaves e gerenciáveis)

Consiste no seguinte (acompanhe os comentários e ponha para rodar):

```js
// construtor do gerenciador de cor, você pode especificar varios parâmetros 
// para obter o seu resultado esperado, como a cor RGB inicial, fator de troca 
// de cor para cada cor, valor maximo e minino que cada cor deve chegar 
// (esse é extremamente util para manter uma cor sempre dentro de uma faixa)
function ColorManager(r /* red */ , g /* green */ , b /* blur */ , fatorR, fatorG, fatorB, maxR, maxG, maxB, minR, minG, minB) {
    return {
        r: r,
        g: g,
        b: b,
        fatorR: fatorR,
        fatorB: fatorB,
        fatorG: fatorG,
        maxR: maxR,
        maxG: maxG,
        maxB: maxB,
        minR: minR,
        minG: minG,
        minB: minB,
        toRGBA: function() {
            return "rgba(" + Math.round(this.r) + ", " + Math.round(this.g) + ", " + Math.round(this.b) + ", 1)";
        },
        apply: function() {
            this.r += this.fatorR;
            this.b += this.fatorB;
            this.g += this.fatorG;
            if (this.r > this.maxR || this.r < this.minR) {
                this.r -= this.fatorR;
                this.fatorR = this.fatorR * -1;
            }
            if (this.g > this.maxG || this.g < this.minG) {
                this.g -= this.fatorG;
                this.fatorG = this.fatorG * -1;
            }  
            if (this.b > this.maxB || this.b < this.minB) {
                this.b -= this.fatorB;
                this.fatorB = this.fatorB * -1;
            }
            return this;
        }
    };
};
    
// aqui você faz todas as configurações do Color
var cor1 = new ColorManager(0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0);
var cor2 = new ColorManager(255, 255, 255, 1, 2, 3, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0);

// cria o timer
setInterval(function() {
    $("body").css({
        background: "linear-gradient(to right, " + cor1.apply().toRGBA() + "," + cor2.apply().toRGBA() + ")"
    });
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Para testar configurações**

[Teste alterando os parâmetros nesse jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/582a72eu/7/)