# Movimentar background do texto

Tags: jquery, css3

Pessoal preciso colocar e animar um degrade como background de uma fonte com um texto escrito.

Preciso que este degradê seja aplicado na fonte (não atrás do texto) e que fique movimentando da esquerda para a direita indefinidamente. Como eu faço isto com CSS ou JQuery?

O background tenho ele tanto em imagem como em CSS.
Degradê em CSS:

```
background: #f44730; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #f44730 0%, #f7f02e 26%, #2dba1d 51%, #2375db 76%, #d11100 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#f44730), color-stop(26%,#f7f02e), color-stop(51%,#2dba1d), color-stop(76%,#2375db), color-stop(100%,#d11100)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #f44730 0%,#f7f02e 26%,#2dba1d 51%,#2375db 76%,#d11100 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #f44730 0%,#f7f02e 26%,#2dba1d 51%,#2375db 76%,#d11100 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #f44730 0%,#f7f02e 26%,#2dba1d 51%,#2375db 76%,#d11100 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #f44730 0%,#f7f02e 26%,#2dba1d 51%,#2375db 76%,#d11100 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f44730', endColorstr='#d11100',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

Comment: Verifique se [essas respostas a essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55920/transi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-cores-gradient-automaticamente-de-forma-suave), já não lhe ajudam.

Comment: Olha todas deram certo mas eu preciso que o background estaja dentro da Font e não por traz da letra. Tipo de vez a cor da letra ser preta sera um degrade. Obrigado

Comment: @JoaoNivaldo você não explicou isso na pergunta.

Comment: Perdão me expressei mal no começo da explicação.

Comment: A título de curiosidade, existe o `-webkit-background-clip:text` que faz justamente o que precisa: Aplicar a cor de *background* no texto. Mas este não é um valor padronizado, ele não existe na especificação e foi implementado somente em navegadores -webkit-. Creio que terá que recorrer ao uso de Javascript mesmo - [ver no Google Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/rnxn/hozv4k00/) - quem sabe um dia vire algo padronizado. **^^**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na falta de uma resposta que atinja 100% os problemas do AP, me arrisco a publicar uma alternativa utilizando [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction), que consiste no seguinte (código comentado explicando o que é cada parte):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%">

  <!-- Aqui você informa seu texto -->
  <!-- Também é possivel setar o tamanho da font do texto, com o atributo "font-size" -->
  <!-- Text utiliza o #pattern (que é o background animado) declarado nos defs como fill -->
  <text x="50%" text-anchor="middle" y="50%" fill="url(#pattern)" font-size="32pt">StackOverflow beta em Português</text>

  <defs>
    <!-- A declaração do gradient -->
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0">
      <!-- As cores do gradient -->
      <!-- No caso você poderia declarar quantas cores você desejar, especificando os percentuais de offset -->
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#33235b;" />
      <stop offset="25%" style="stop-color:#D62229;" />
      <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:#E97639;" />
      <stop offset="75%" style="stop-color:#792042;" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#33235b;" />
    </linearGradient>

    <!-- Utilize dois gradientes em conjunto para uma animação perfeita  -->
    <!-- A declaração das animações -->
    <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <!-- Primeiro frame de animação, animando de 0% até 100% no eixo x-->
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)">
        <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="x" from="0" to="100%" dur="7s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </rect>
      <!-- Segundo frame de animação, animando de -100% até 0% no eixo x, preenchendo a animação do frame anterior -->
      <rect x="-100%" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)">
        <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="x" from="-100%" to="0" dur="7s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </rect>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

As principais alterações que você pode necessitar fazer no código para ajustar a seu caso são:

1. Alterar os valores de `width` e `height` da tag `svg`, para valores em `px` conforme necessidade;
2. Alterar o tamanho da fonte do texto, atribuindo o valor desejado em `font-size` da tag `text`;
3. Alterar o texto que deve ser exibido, atribuindo o texto desejado no conteúdo da tag `text`;
4. Alterar as cores e proporções de gradiente na tag `linearGradient` com `id=gradient`;
5. Alterar a velocidade da animação do background da fonte do texto, alterando o valor do atributo `dur` nas tags `rect` pertencente ao `pattern` (Obs: para manter a consistência da animação é necessário que o valor do atributo `dur` seja o mesmo nas duas tags `rect`);

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/80pd0dp1/3/)

Comment: Muito obrigado deu certinho.

Comment: @JoaoNivaldo, fico feliz de poder ter te ajudado =). Já que a resposta foi marcada como aceita, tentei melhora-la. Comentei melhor a resposta e os códigos, demonstrando o que é cada parte, e o que faz. Para que essa resposta também possa ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema que o seu.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode criar uma Timer `javascript` que vai incrementando e movendo o seu `background`

Por exemplo:

```
$(function(){
    var x = 0;
    function transacao(){
        x-=100;
        $('h1.move').css('background-position', x + 'px 0');
    }
    transacao();
    setInterval(transacao, 10050);
});
```

[Exemplo online.](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/eo3hn3sf/6/)

> Obs: Você deve trocar a cor de inicio ou fim do degrade, para que não haja uma troca de cor brusca como está no exemplo.

---

**Edit -- Para aplicar esse efeito ao texto ao invés do background**

Esse `css` copia o `background` para o texto, com o atributo [background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)(pelo que vi não parece que trabalha para todos os browser, testei no Chrome):

```
background-clip: text;
text-fill-color: transparent;
```

> Obs: Como citado nos comentário por @renan, `background-clip: text` só funciona no Chrome dessa forma: `-webkit-background-clip: text`, e nos demais browser não trabalha, teria que procurar algo alternativo. :(

[Exemplo online, somente no Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/eo3hn3sf/8/)

Comment: +1 estava pensando em algo desse tipo, mas você foi bem mais rápido... :) Apenas gostaria de sugerir - para reduzir a carga do código JS - que se usasse um intervalo bem maior em conjunto com uma transição CSS. [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/eo3hn3sf/4/) (sem todos os prefixos para `transition`; teste no Chrome).

Comment: @mgibsonbr, rápido. =) hehe. Uhm, quando sai para o almoço pensei nisso, que adicionar um `transition`, para deixar a transação mais suave. Agora com sua sugestão, vou atualizar a resposta, obrigado pela sugestão.

Comment: Não existe `background-clip:text` na especificação Fernando, esse valor `text` foi implementado somente em navegadores webkit. Experimente abrir o mesmo exemplo online no Firefox.

Comment: @renan, você tem razão, que vi a propriedade no [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip), e achei que funcionava para os novos browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Utilizando keyframe do CSS3 você consegue animar sem nenhum JS.

```css
@keyframes animatedBackground {
 0% { background-position: -1145px 0; }
 100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
 0% { background-position: -1145px 0; }
 100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
 0% { background-position: -1145px 0; }
 100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes animatedBackground {
 0% { background-position: -1145px 0; }
 100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes animatedBackground {
 0% { background-position: -1145px 0; }
 100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}

#header-animation {
    color: white;
    font-family: Georgia;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 220px;
 width: 100%; 
 height: 200px;
 background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #f44730 0%, #f7f02e 26%, #2dba1d 51%, #2375db 76%, #d11100 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#f44730), color-stop(26%,#f7f02e), color-stop(51%,#2dba1d), color-stop(76%,#2375db), color-stop(100%,#d11100)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #f44730 0%,#f7f02e 26%,#2dba1d 51%,#2375db 76%,#d11100 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #f44730 0%,#f7f02e 26%,#2dba1d 51%,#2375db 76%,#d11100 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #f44730 0%,#f7f02e 26%,#2dba1d 51%,#2375db 76%,#d11100 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to right,  #f44730 0%,#f7f02e 26%,#2dba1d 51%,#2375db 76%,#d11100 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f44730', endColorstr='#d11100',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
 background-position: 0px 0px;

 animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
 -ms-animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header-animation">Título</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

Na ausência de uma solução *cross-browsers* em CSS para aplicar um degradê ao *background* de um texto, sugiro o uso de `canvas` para atingir o seu objetivo. [Esse exemplo no W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_filltext.asp) faz exatamente o que você quer, só faltando animar o *gradient* com o tempo. Combinando essa técnica com [o método que descrevi em uma outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55935/215) para fazer a animação via `setInterval`, temos:

```js
var texto = "stackoverflow em Português";

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font="30px Verdana";

// As cores que compõem o degradê
var cores = [
    [255,0,0],
    [255,255,0],
    [0,255,0],
    [0,0,255],
    [128,0,128]
];
var shift = 1; // A transição entre uma e outra, de 0 a 1
var passos = ["0", "0.25", "0.5", "0.75", "1"];

// Faz uma média ponderada de cada componente das cores 1 e 2
function calcular(cor1, cor2, progresso) {
  var ret = [];
  for ( var i = 0 ; i < cor1.length ; i++ )
    ret[i] = Math.round(cor2[i] * progresso + cor1[i] * (1 - progresso));
  return ret;
}

setInterval(function() {
    // Ajusta o progresso entre uma cor e outra
    shift -= 0.04;
    if ( shift < 0 ) { // Ao chegar a zero, circula as cores na lista
        shift = 1;
        cores.unshift(cores.pop()); // Retira-se a última e insere-a no início
    }
    
    // Create gradient
    var gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,c.width,0);
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ) {
        var anterior = (i == 0 ? 4 : i-1); // A última junta com a primeira
        var media = calcular(cores[anterior], cores[i], shift);
        var cor = "rgb(" + media.join(",") + ")";
        gradient.addColorStop(passos[i], cor);
    }
    
    // Fill with gradient
    ctx.fillStyle=gradient;
    ctx.fillText(texto,10,30); // Desenha o texto de fato
}, 250);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500"></canvas>
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q0uq9o4d/). Note que essa abordagem não é sem desvantagens:

1. Você terá que colocar o `canvas` dentro do `h1` (ou *em vez do* `h1`), e o texto deve estar numa variável JavaScript;
2. Se a tela for redimensionada, ou a fonte alterada, o texto não acompanhará automaticamente as mudanças - isso precisa ser feito por código;
3. Nem todo *browser* dá suporte a `canvas` ([IE 8- não suporta](http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas), a menos que se use [um *shim*](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: +1 .É uma das unicas alternativas mesmo, ou assim ou com svg. =)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar um arquivo .gif como o *background*, retirando toda a implementação necessária em CSS e Javascript.
Exemplo:

```css
body{
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx8MT.gif');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
d
```

Comment: Eu gostaria usando o CSS e no máximo o JQuery não gostaria de ter que criar a animação em gif, pois o texto e bem grande e a imagem vai ficar pesada. Obrigado